# Segmentation of a geometrical shapes

Tags: opencv, rectangles, image-segmentation

I am trying to segment a QFN package on the x-ray image of the PCB. The general description of QNF package is that it's square or rectangle in the centre with the rectangular pins on the edge. The example is on this image: [image: QFN package]

I can segment the rectangles on the x-ray image quite good but I dont know how to write the condition to segment only the QFN package. The package can be square or rectangle and can have different number of pins on the edge. My idea is to check the close neighborhood of each rectangle filter out rectangles that are too big and somehow check if the remaining rectangles are all around. Is there a better approach? Or how would you check if the big rectangle is surrounded by the small ones?  [image: Real image]

I am using python 3.5 and OpenCV 3.1

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be a bit long, I would give you some basic techniques and guidelines along with some advanced suggestions to increase the accuracy of QNF package detection.

Assuming that you already have the red marked contours stored in a variable `contours`.

First of all define the upper and lower limit of contour area you want to filter. As per the given image, the area range of central region comes out to be:

```
CHIP_CENTER_AREA_LOWER, CHIP_CENTER_AREA_UPPER = 20*1000, 25*1000
```

So we iterate over all contours and filter the contour which have area in above range, it would eliminate the smaller contours, and we would be examining only the larger contours.

```
probable_chip_center_contour_idx = []
for i in xrange(len(contours)):
    cnt = contours[i]
    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    if CHIP_CENTER_AREA_LOWER < area < CHIP_CENTER_AREA_UPPER:
        probable_chip_center_contour_idx.append(i)
```

Now after filtering out probable contours on basis of area, we would check the number of neighbouring contours(pins). Those central contours which would have expected number of neighbouring contours within a given radius would be out final result.

```
radius = 80
EXPECTED_NEIGHBOURING_PINS = 28
for i in probable_chip_center_contour_idx:
    cnt = contours[i]
    cnt_bounding_rect = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    extended_cnt_bounding_rect = [cnt_bounding_rect[0] - radius, cnt_bounding_rect[1] - radius,
                                  cnt_bounding_rect[2] + 2*radius, cnt_bounding_rect[3] + 2*radius]
    neighbouring_contours = 0
    for probable_neighbouring_contour in contours:
        probable_bounding_rect = cv2.boundingRect(probable_neighbouring_contour)
        if is_rect_inside(probable_bounding_rect, extended_cnt_bounding_rect):
            neighbouring_contours += 1
    if neighbouring_contours > EXPECTED_NEIGHBOURING_PINS:
        print "QFN Found"
```